# GROUP BY com 2 Tabelas

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Preciso fazer um select com `JOIN` em duas tabelas mas não estou conseguindo agrupar para não repetir as linhas. Segue a expressão SQL:

```
SELECT 
       Andamento.NumeroProcesso, 
       Andamento.Chave, 
       Andamento.Codigo, 
       Andamento.DataAnda, 
       Andamento.Andamento, 
       Andamento.AdvogadoID

FROM   Andamento FULL OUTER JOIN Processo 

ON     Andamento.NumeroProcesso = Processo.NumeroProcesso

WHERE  (Processo.Irrecuperavel = 1) AND (DATEDIFF(MONTH, 
       Andamento.DataAnda,GETDATE()) >= 6)
```

Quando tento a cláusula:

```
GROUP BY Andamento.NumeroProcesso
```

Obtenho o seguente erro:

> A coluna 'Andamento.Chave' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não está contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula `GROUP BY`

Comment: já tentou colocar, GROUP BY Andamento.NumeroProcesso, Andamento.Chave ?

Comment: A solução vai variar de acordo com o relacionamento e dados dessas tabelas, tente incluir na pergunta o resultado esperado. Mas uma coisa é certa a sintaxe do group by deve conter todos os campos que não estiverem contindos em um função de agregação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mudei minha lógica para fazer o select fincado assim:

```
SELECT       
        Andamento.NumeroProcesso

FROM    Andamento LEFT OUTER JOIN Processo 

ON      Andamento.NumeroProcesso = Processo.NumeroProcesso
WHERE
    (Processo.Irrecuperavel = 1) AND 
    (DATEDIFF(MONTH, Andamento.DataAnda, GETDATE()) >= 6)

GROUP BY Andamento.NumeroProcesso
```

Onde obtenho uma lista apenas de NumeroProcesso sem repetição, e depois via code C# obtenho os dados relacionando a lista de NumeroProcesso.

Comment: Salvo engano de minha parte, um processo pode ou não ter andamento. Por exemplo, processos novos podem ainda não ter lançamentos de andamento, certo? Desta forma, me parece que a junção correta é `FROM Processo left join Andamento on ...`. // Se montar corretamente a junção, não é necessária a cláusula GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Linhas repetidas, quando não são o resultado esperado, geralmente ocorrem quando a junção está incorreta ou incompleta. Se um processo pode ter nenhuma, uma ou mais informações de andamento, me parece que o relacionamento entre as tabelas Processo e Andamento deve ser do tipo LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Avalie:

```
-- código #1 v2
SELECT 
       P.NumeroProcesso, 
       A.Chave, 
       A.Codigo, 
       A.DataAnda, 
       A.Andamento, 
       A.AdvogadoID

FROM   Processo as P
       left join Andamento as A on P.NumeroProcesso = A.NumeroProcesso

WHERE  P.Irrecuperavel = 1 
       and (A.NumeroProcesso is null
            or A.DataAnda < dateadd(month, -6, current_timestamp)
           );
```